# Problem with laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm new to laravel and facing problem with Eloquent relationships. I am developing a website where Users/doctors have many patient records. So I want to make one to many relationship with User and patient model. The problem is I'm getting all the patient data belongs to every users/doctors where I obviously need only patients data that belongs to that authenticated user/doctor. What I am doing wrong here?

This is my User model file. User.php.

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
use Notifiable,SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function patient()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Bioctor\patient','user_id');

        //return $this->belongsTo(patient::class);
    }
}
```

This is patient model. patient.php.

```
class patient extends Model{
use SoftDeletes;

   protected $fillable = [
     'user_id','patient_name', 'slug', 'age', 'sex', 'case_title','case_des','blood_group','report_image_url'
   ];

   public function user()
    {
      //  return $this->belongsTo();

       // return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is my patient controller code.

```
class PatientController extends Controller{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index()
{
    return response()->json(User::with(['patient'])->get());      
}

public function create()
{
    return view('patient.patientInput');
}

public function store(CreatePatientRequest $request)
{        

    $request->uploadPatientImage()
            ->storePatientImage();    
    return redirect()->back();
}

public function show($id)
{
    //
    //dd(User::with(['patient'])->get());
}

public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

This is what I'm getting at edit.index Ior patientcontroller@index route. This is json output in my browser. I've two user and four patient entry in database. I am getting all patients records of every user.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"rnlio1995","email":"rnlio1995@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2018-10-10 15:36:58","updated_at":"2018-10-10 15:36:58","patient":[{"id":1,"user_id":"1","patient_name":"aaaaaaaaaaaaa","slug":"aaaaaaaaaaaaa","age":"44","sex":"Male","case_title":"cough","case_des":"fsfsdfdsf","blood_group":"A+","report_image_url":"patient\/aaaaaaaaaaaaa.jpg","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2018-10-10 15:37:38","updated_at":"2018-10-10 15:37:38"},{"id":2,"user_id":"1","patient_name":"noor","slug":"noor","age":"7","sex":"Male","case_title":"cough","case_des":"hgfhfhf","blood_group":"A+","report_image_url":"patient\/rnlio1995_5bbf878505fa8.jpg","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2018-10-11 17:25:25","updated_at":"2018-10-11 17:25:25"},{"id":3,"user_id":"1","patient_name":"noor","slug":"noor","age":"44","sex":"Male","case_title":"cough","case_des":"yuyguyguy","blood_group":"A+","report_image_url":"patient\/rnlio1995_5bbf8c18e75cc.jpg","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2018-10-11 17:44:56","updated_at":"2018-10-11 17:44:56"}]},{"id":2,"name":"noor","email":"rn19@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2018-10-11 17:47:01","updated_at":"2018-10-11 17:47:01","patient":[{"id":4,"user_id":"2","patient_name":"noor","slug":"noor","age":"55","sex":"Male","case_title":"cough","case_des":"hihiuh","blood_group":"A+","report_image_url":"patient\/noor_5bbf8cae477eb.jpg","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2018-10-11 17:47:26","updated_at":"2018-10-11 17:47:26"}]}]
```

This is the image of output.
[JSON output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6B5p.png)

Comment: What is the version of Laravel you are using?

Comment: It's laravel 5.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want patients data, then you don't want to use `with`. `->with()` means that you want to fetch your data together with the relations that you specified. That's why `User::with(['patient'])->get()` would give you all users together with all patients data.

Also, since you probably have multiple patients for one doctor, you should define relationship using `patients()` (plural) to make things clearer:

```
public function patients()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Bioctor\Patient', 'user_id');
}
```

You can then use following code to get patients of specified user:

```
//find specified user
$user = User::findOrFail($id);

//fetch relations
$patients = $user->patients;

foreach ($patients as $patient) {
    //do what you intend to do with each patient
}
```

Notice we don't use `patients()` with parenthesis, we just access the relation like normal properties. Of course you have to specify `$id` or use `Laravel`'s `Auth::user()` facade to get specified/authenticated user.

For more information, check out official manual on this:
[Laravel Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)